# Properly declaring unique dictionaries with copy()

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to read through sequencing data and classify the contained mutations. The problem I think I am having is not properly declaring each of the nested dictionaries such that they are unique.

This is how I am creating my data structure:

```
baseDict = {'A':0, 'T':0, 'G':0, 'C':0}
varDict = {'A':baseDict.copy(), 'T':baseDict.copy(), 'G':baseDict.copy(), 'C':baseDict.copy()}
fullDict = {'oncoSites':varDict.copy(), 'oncoGenes':varDict.copy(), 'TIIIRegions':varDict.copy()}
```

Then I am adding any particular mutation I read in like this:

```
fullDict['oncoSites'][j][k] += 1
```

The problem is that when I add a mutation it is added to multiple dictionaries. As an example Take if I read in a reference base of `T` and variant of `C` that is found in `oncoSites` then add it as:

```
fullDict['oncoSites'][T][C] += 1
```

The output I get is this:

```
{'TIIIRegions': {'A': {'A': 0, 'C': 0, 'G': 0, 'T': 0},
                 'C': {'A': 0, 'C': 0, 'G': 0, 'T': 0},
                 'G': {'A': 0, 'C': 0, 'G': 0, 'T': 0},
                 'T': {'A': 0, 'C': 1, 'G': 0, 'T': 0}},
 'oncoGenes': {'A': {'A': 0, 'C': 0, 'G': 0, 'T': 0},
               'C': {'A': 0, 'C': 0, 'G': 0, 'T': 0},
               'G': {'A': 0, 'C': 0, 'G': 0, 'T': 0},
               'T': {'A': 0, 'C': 1, 'G': 0, 'T': 0}},
 'oncoSites': {'A': {'A': 0, 'C': 0, 'G': 0, 'T': 0},
               'C': {'A': 0, 'C': 0, 'G': 0, 'T': 0},
               'G': {'A': 0, 'C': 0, 'G': 0, 'T': 0},
               'T': {'A': 0, 'C': 1, 'G': 0, 'T': 0}}}
```

How can I increment only a single dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need a [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html).

Use:

```
{'oncoSites':deepcopy(varDict), 'oncoGenes':deepcopy(varDict), 'TIIIRegions':deepcopy(varDict)}
```

What was happening is: when you did `varDict.copy(..)` you were copying the references of the copy of `baseDict`